# Android events thru UI service and async task

Tags: android

My UI create the service and the service create the thread.
I need to change UI in flavor of the events in the async taks.

I had try with Broadcast but that cause my app to crash. Cause i cant connect the correct content.

How can i do that?

EDIT, add some example code:

Main UI:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {   // Constructor.
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(eventCfgCompleta,
                new IntentFilter(Constants.CFG_COMPLETA));

        Intent intentMemoryService = new Intent(
                getApplicationContext(), mw_service.class);

        startService(intentMemoryService);
}

private BroadcastReceiver eventCfgCompleta = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
            // Get extra data included in the Intent
            // Si la app tiene cfg, pasa a ActivityConectandoMW
            Intent intent_activity = new Intent(context, ActivityConectandoMW.class);
            intent_activity.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent_activity);
        }
};
}
```

Service:

```
public class mw_service extends Service
{
@Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
    {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "Servicio creado...");
        sendMessage("ON CREATE SERVICE");

    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startID)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "Servicio onStart...");
        conex = new conexion_thread( getApplicationContext(),
                                         MWserial,
                                         MWpassword,
                                         casilla,
                                         webkey );
            conex.execute();
        }
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "Servicio onDestroy...");

        sendMessage("ON STOP SERVICE");

        Log.d(TAG, "Servicio destruido...");
    }

private void sendMessage(String msg) {
  Log.d("sender", "Broadcasting message");
  Intent intent = new Intent(msg);
  // You can also include some extra data.
  intent.putExtra("message", msg);
  LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
}
}
```

AsyncTask:

```
public class conexion_thread extends AsyncTask <Void, String, Void> {
public conexion_thread( Context context, String serial, String MWpass, String cas, String webk ){
        // Recibe un textView perteneciente a la UI para pasar datos entre UI y el Thread.
        super();
        this.context= context;

        cambio_status= false;
        status="";
        ipequipo="";

        IPwanCelular= "";   //IP WAN de este equipo
        IPlanCelular= "";   //IP WAN de este equipo
        IPlanMW= "";        //IP LAN del MW buscado
        IPwanMW= "";        //IP WAN del MW buscado
        MWenLAN= false;     //el MW esta en LAN

        MWserial= serial;   // Numero de serial del MW.
        MWpassword= MWpass; // Password del MW.
        casilla= cas;       // Casilla de VM telefonico del usuario.
        webkey= webk;       // Clave web del usuario. 
    }

@Override
    protected Void doInBackground( Void... params ){

        // Mientras que no se quiera salir de la tarea.
        while( estado_conex != EST_CONEX_QUIT ){
            // Ver si hay que dormir o procesar.
            if( sleep_thread > 0 ){
                // Si el tiempo de dormir es mayor que cero se duerme la tarea.
                try{
                    // Pone a dormir el thread.
                    Thread.sleep(sleep_thread);

                    // Ver si hay datos/red al terminar de  esperar.
                    if( !isNetworkAvailable(context) ){
                        // Si no hay conexion vuelve a polear hasta que la encuentre.
                        setStatus( "No hay conexion a internet." );
                        // Pone a dormir 1 segundo.
                        sleep_thread=1000;
                        // Cuando se pierde la conexion, debe volver a registrar porque puede cambiar el IP.
                        estado_conex= EST_CONEX_INIT;
                        sendMessage(Constants.SIN_CONEXION);
                    }else{
                        // Borra el tiempo a dormir ni bien termino de dormir asi procesa.
                        sleep_thread= 0;
                    }

                }catch( InterruptedException e ){
                    // Error en el sleep.
                    setStatus( "Error interno (001)" );
                    // Interrupt en la tarea, lo mata el OS por otro lado.
                    // Exit.
                    break;
                }

            }else{
                // here i do the magic, but the 
// Maquina de estados.
                switch( estado_conex ){
                case EST_CONEX_INIT:
                    // Fijarse de tener todos los datos y conexion a internet.
                    publishProgress( "EST_CONEX_INIT" );

                    if( MWserial.isEmpty()   ||
                        MWpassword.isEmpty() ||
                        casilla.isEmpty()    ||
                        webkey.isEmpty()     ){
                        // Si hay un campo vacio, no se puede iniciar nada.
                        setStatus( "Faltan datos de conexion." );
                        // No cambia el estado, va a dormir y reintenta.
                        sleep_thread= 1000*60*1;    //En ms. Son 1 minuto.
                    }
                    // Esta todo OK para intentar conectar.
                    estado_conex= EST_CONEX_GET_RND_DYNIP;
                    sendMessage(Constants.CONECTANDO_A_MW);
                    break;

                case EST_CONEX_GET_RND_DYNIP:
                    // 1- Obtener la clave para DynIP
                    publishProgress( "EST_CONEX_GET_RND_DYNIP" );

                    claveDynIP= getClaveDynIP();
                    if( (claveDynIP.isEmpty())  || 
                        (claveDynIP == "ERROR") ){
                        // Si esta vacia o es ERROR
                        // Error al obtener el random. 
                        // No cambia el estado, va a dormir y reintenta.
                        sleep_thread= 1000*60*3;    //En ms. Son 3 minutos.
                        estado_conex= EST_CONEX_INIT;
                    }else{
                        // 2- Obtener el IP del equipo y del celular.
                        ipequipo= getIPs();
                        if( ipequipo.isEmpty() ){
                            // Si esta vacio es error.
                            sleep_thread= 1000*60*3;    //En ms. Son 3 minutos.
                            // Pasa a estado inicial para volver a empezar.
                            estado_conex= EST_CONEX_INIT;
                        }else{
                            // OK, pasar al siguiente estado.
                            estado_conex= EST_CONEX_GET_MW_SERIAL;
                            sendMessage(Constants.IPS_RESUELTOS, ipequipo);
                        }
                    }
                    break;

                case EST_CONEX_GET_MW_SERIAL:
                    // 3- Obtenes el random/serial del MW para encriptar.
                    publishProgress( "EST_CONEX_GET_MW_SERIAL" );

                    claveMW= obtenerClaveMW(ipequipo);
                    if( claveMW.isEmpty() ){
                        //Error!
                        // No cambia el estado, va a dormir y reintenta.
                        sleep_thread= 1000*60*3;    //En ms. Son 3 minutos.
                        estado_conex= EST_CONEX_GET_RND_DYNIP;
                    }else{
                        // OK
                        estado_conex= EST_CONEX_POLL_MW;
                    }
                    break;

                case EST_CONEX_POLL_MW:
                    // 4- Ya tengo todo para polear e indicarle que estoy online.
                    publishProgress( "EST_CONEX_POLL_MW" );

                    if( isClaveMWValid() == false ){
                        // Primero ver si no vencio la clave.
                        // Si vencio, volver a pedirla.
                        estado_conex= EST_CONEX_GET_MW_SERIAL;
                    }
                    if( polearMW(ipequipo, MWserial, MWpassword, casilla, webkey, 1, 2, claveMW, getIPAddress()) ){
                        // Esta conectado. No cambia el estado, polea cada 1min para mantenerse vivo. 
                        sleep_thread= 1000*59*5;    //En ms. Son aprox 5 minutos.
                        sendMessage(Constants.CONECTADO_A_MW, ""+VoiceMailMsgNumber );
                    }else{
                        // Error!
                        sleep_thread= 1000*60*1;    //En ms. Es 1 minuto.
                        // Pasa a obtener serial nuevamente.
                        estado_conex= EST_CONEX_GET_MW_SERIAL;
                    }
                    break;

                default:
                    // Error se corrompio el estado del poleo.
                    break;
                }
            }
            if( cambio_status ){
                publishProgress( status );
            }
        }

        if( estado_conex == EST_CONEX_QUIT ){
            publishProgress( "DEBUG: matando tarea." );
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
       //String aux= t_local.getText() + "\n";
       //aux= aux + progress[0];
       //t_local.setText(aux);
       //t_local.append(progress[0]+"\n");
    }

private void sendMessage(String... msgs) {
        // Obtiene la cantidad de parametros.
        int count = msgs.length;
        if( count > 0 ){
            // Crea intent.
            Intent intent = new Intent(msgs[0]);
            for( int i=1 ; i<count; i++ ){
                intent.putExtra("message_"+count, msgs[i]);

            }
            /****The app crash here*****/
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent);
        }
    }
```

Hope you can understand my creepy code.

Comment: Could you provide some sample code?

Comment: Done! @Michael Dodd

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can double-check how that crash ocurred. The broadcasting system is a good way to go. More exactly, see [LocalBroadcastManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html).

If you will be more specific in explaining (perhaps showing with code) what you are trying to do, maybe people can help you out.

Comment: After a first glance, I would suggest you to look into [IntentService](https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html), it may help you to get rid off that AsyncTask. Also, you don't seem to unregister your receiver. About the crash, what is the exact error? (an error log will help)

Comment: i put the service and the asynk task in a intentService. Currently trying making work, ill report again soon.

Comment: I solve the problem, was a miss calculated array access.

Comment: But now my IntentService die when the task manager kill the app.

Comment: I need a thread that is polling a connection. And i need to send events to my main app to handle UI. Need calls notifications and msg notif.